# Google detecta páginas extrañas en sitio web

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

- Tengo un `sitemap` con 29 páginas en un sitio Wordpress.
- En la Consola de Google - Cobertura me aparecen otras 4 páginas adicionales extrañas del tipo

  - /ef0824g-microphonics/4842101/londonization.mom  o
  - /hnip/s7-1500-data-logging.html
- Ahora, con un Redirect 301 van al home que configuré en el .htaccess
- El sitio fue hackeado.  Ya se cambió los archivos de Wordpress, menos la carpeta `wp-content` y el `wp-config.php` y el sitio se ha recuperado.
- La base de datos no se ha trabajado.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo ver dónde localizar esas y otras páginas extrañas, pero en el servidor?

Comment: Estaría bueno que te fijes en las herramientas de bing de Microsoft (si es que no te has registrado allí). De esta manera podrás ver que otras páginas extrañas te podrían salir y comparar con el de Google. Asimismo podrías hacer uso del comando __site:www.tuweb.com__ en los buscadores para así ver como te está indexando tu sitio y si aparecen esas páginas extrañas.

Comment: Hola Damian García, gracias por tu respuesta.  
En site:sitioweb.com aparecían muchas páginas extrañas en idiomas raros, ya no, pero esas páginas no se pueden ver y sospecho que tienen que ver con el problema que había; al tratar de ingresar al wp-admin daba error 403
Quiero saber dónde o cómo ver esas y otras páginas extrañas que haya, pero en el servidor.